# OS 2.2 on the Samsung Moment

Tags: 2.2-froyo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When will my phone get Android 2.2 (FroYo)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2696/when-will-my-phone-get-android-2-2-froyo)

I currently have a Samsung Moment which has OS 2.1. Will I ever be able to upgrade to 2.2?

Is the hardware capable of handling 2.2?
If so, when will this happen?
What's the best way to be informed of any announcements related to this upgrade?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of right now there will not be an official 2.2 release for the Moment.  [Here's a thread to keep updated.](http://community.sprint.com/baw/thread/32268?InQuiraCrawler=1#__highlight&id16=samsung+moment+2.2)